# Symbols that should exists in IText but are not recognized

Tags: java, itext

I am stuggling for 3 days and cannot find the solution

from this code:

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream; 
    import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
    import java.io.IOException; 
    import java.io.InputStream; 
    import java.security.MessageDigest; 
    import java.security.cert.Certificate;    
    import org.javasign.operators.CryptokiGenerator;    
    import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle; 
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary; 
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName; 
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7; 
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader; 
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance; 
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper; 
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfString; 
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignature;

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("signed.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    sap.setCrypto(null, certs, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);
    sap.setReason("How to use iText and Javasign with an Italian smart card");
    sap.setLocation("Italy");
    sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(30, 750, 500, 565), 1, null);
    sap.setExternalDigest(new byte[128], new byte[20], "RSA");
    sap.preClose();

    PdfPKCS7 sig = sap.getSigStandard().getSigner();
```

Netbeans cannot find symbols: SELF_SIGNED, setExternalDigest() and getSigStandard()

I have added all those libraries above and also the jars so there is no problem with my includes.
The documentation tells about those methods including this constant so I am don´t know what is going on.

I am using IText 5.4.0
Any help?

Comment: If you want to create digital signatures with current iText versions, please result the white paper [Digital Signatures for PDF documents - iText](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures/). The signing API in iText changed considerably in the recent months and years.

Answer (score 1):

> Netbeans cannot find symbols: SELF_SIGNED, setExternalDigest() and getSigStandard()

According to the [IText (5.4.1) API documentation](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfSignatureAppearance.html), these methods do not exist in the `PdfSignatureAppearance` class.